# How to close web form using javascript vb.net asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

This is my scenario. If the session is expired in our system/application it is redirecting to the log-in page.

If i open the application on two different browsers,If session is timed out in one of the broswer window,it must close the other window too.In my case ,i can still process the 2nd browser/window(i can click buttons and etc.,).

Please suggest me what i can do here

```
<pre> 


<code>
This is my java script code:
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
<!--
     function closeWindow() {
         self.close();
     }
// -->
</script>


This is my server side code

 If Not clsUserSession.IsSessionExist(getUserid, False) Then


                Me.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "CloseWindowScript", "closeWindow();", True)
                Exit Sub

            End If

This is my java script code:
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
<!--
     function closeWindow() {
         self.close();
     }
// -->
</script>
```

Comment: Why not do it in the server-side? Javascript is commonly used for client-side tasks.

Comment: @mykieee based on your requirement what you need is the [Form Authentication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdt4thhy.aspx) , so that how many windows you open when a particular session is expired , user will be redirected to the Login Page.

Comment: @CrushSundae my window is in client side. i tried the me.dispose but its not working. i just want if the session of the user is already time out. if he click the any button it will close the window. 
thank you for the respond so much appriciated

Comment: @CrushSundae yes i tried. i ask also my friends. they told if you want to close the page use javascript. i already search in internet it dosent work. :(

Comment: May I ask what are you planning to do here? I just want to clarify 'cause I am thinking a better way (I think) to approach this like redirecting them to another page saying that the session has expired or something like that, rather than just closing the form.

Comment: @Webruster 2 windows. if the main page has session time out it will go to login page. but the other window is still functioning.

Comment: @CrushSundae hmm i have a function that checking the session of the user, so i put it in the buttons of that web form. so if the user click any button there my function checking if the session is existing if not close the window. but  sunddenly this code not working :(

Comment: Yeah, that's what just I read in your post. I mean the flow of your pages. I'm not that good in web dev but what do you mean by "close"? Is the one you're calling a "window" really a web page?

Comment: @CrushSundae yes sir. is web page. im also new using asp.net.

Comment: @mykieee if you able to configure Form Autentication , second page will not be  functioning if session is expired.

Answer (score -1):

Hope thses will help you

[Try with www3school](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_close.asp)

[Window close function api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close)

Comment: Link-only answers are not useful, you should include the relevant parts of the linked information in the answer itself.